# How to prevent button calling the previous event when rapidly tap buttons near each other

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs

##### Problem:

I'm making a custom keyboard display on a website because I wanted to add specific key features to it. Currently, there is a bug in my custom keyboard when if I have buttons `x` and `y` then I rapidly click from `x -> y` button it causes the `y` event click to call the `same event as previous onClick` which on this case is `x` and also vice versa.

This issue only seems to occur on ios mobile devices. so far I've only tested it on `iPhone 8` and `iPhone 12 Pro Max` `safari browsers` but I'm suspecting it's an iOS thing.

##### Goal:

I want to prevent this issue from happening and still be able to rapidly to type with my custom keyboard. How can I fix this?

##### Attempts:

I have tried a few different approaches but none of them worked:

- separating the functions for both buttons
- adding keys into the buttons
- disabling the previously clicked button for 100ms-400ms

##### Sample Code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const spacingStyle = {
  fontSize: '14px',
  marginBottom: '10px',
}

const buttonStyle = {
  background: 'gray',
  color: 'White',
  marginRight: '5px',
  padding: '0 10px',
}

const Test = () => {
  const [content, setContent] = useState('');
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState('');

  const appendToText = (e, char) => {
    setContent(content + char);
    setClicked(e.target.innerText);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <p style={spacingStyle}>Content: {content}</p>
      <p style={spacingStyle}>Clicked: {clicked}</p>
      <button key="key-x" style={buttonStyle} onClick={(e) => appendToText(e, 'x')}>X</button>
      <button key="key-y" style={buttonStyle} onClick={(e) => appendToText(e, 'y')}>Y</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

[Sample image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEiT6.png)

Comment: [Update] I noticed when the distance between the button is far enough (in my case 30px) the button event would behave correctly. Still not solution for it though.